# Why NFL kickers wear different shoes on each foot?

Tags: american-football, equipment, nfl

I was watching some American Football, and I noticed that the kicker Blair Walsh wore a white shoe on his right (kicking) foot, and a black shoe on his left. Is there a reason for this? Does it benefit the kicker somehow?

Comment: In seriousness: are they different makes/models of boot or are they simply the same make/model with different colours? I used to have a pair of adidas which were half red and half white - and the division was a diagonal across the pair together, not each one separately. I've seen players wearing shoes from several manufacturers which were also very different between the left/right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Team trainers and players work within NFL guidelines for player equipment. The colors do not benefit the kicker or team, but must "conform" to NFL equipment guidelines.

See page 28: http://static.nfl.com/static/content/public/image/rulebook/pdfs/8_Rule5_Players_Subs_Equip_GeneralRules.pdf

"*League-approved tri-colored shoes are permitted with black, white, and one
team color.*"

and

"*Punters and placekickers may wear any combination of tri-colored shoes provided that the colors are consistent with those selected by the team and with the policy listed above.*"

Generally speaking, one shoe is important for gripping the turf, the other for striking the ball. Shoe soles may however, vary in their number, arrangement, shape, material, diameter and length of cleats.